# How do I validate custom rest endpoint in loopback 3 non-persistent model?

Tags: validation, loopbackjs, loopback

According to the documentation on loopback about [validation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html%20validation), it can only be performed if the model is derived from persistedModel base. I am using [remote methods](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html) to expose a custom rest endpoint on my model which is derived from generic Model. How do I add validations to it? I thought about using [hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) but they are supported on PersistedModel only.

Is there a way I can add custom validation to non-persistent models?

Answer (score 1):

Validation is intended for models that can be saved to the database, and these are persistent models, in your case you can use the remote hooks
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html